# Fetch json with non ASCI characters like ü, chrome displays network displays correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch-api

I am using fetch native in chrome dev tools.
In the response.json() the data of the job are received but non ascii characters ate bit displays correctly.

The network tab of chrome shows the characters correctly in the response body.

I have tried to set different headers of content type,
UTF-8 and ISO-8891-1.

How can.I see how dev tools of chrome displays correctly the characters?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, I used native `xhttpRequest` and this native function

```
xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=iso-8859-1");
```

which I took from here:

[Displaying accented character in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884747/displaying-accented-character-in-javascript)